# Can we have entanglement entropy in the SYK model?

Tags: entropy, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I know that defining of entanglement entropy and [Ryu-Takayanagi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryu%E2%80%93Takayanagi_conjecture) in the AdS/CFT, can we define these in the SYK model?